# Way to Create Virtual Desktops and Stream Their Contents

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I'm looking for a way to programmatically create multiple "virtual" desktops, and stream their contents to whatever.

Essentially, what macOS apis are these guys https://cindori.org/vrdesktop/  using to create those virtual desktops and additionally how do they get a video stream of it?

Just looking for guidance to the right apis/docs.  No code required :)

Comment: Let's get this to Stack Overflow - API implies code level knowledge and that's off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a kernel extension that simulates a graphics adapter, essentially just rendering everything into a framebuffer. The framebuffer can then be exported as a video stream or whatever you choose.

You can find example source codes to look at here:

https://github.com/tSoniq/displayx

https://github.com/andreacremaschi/Syphon-virtual-screen/tree/develop

https://github.com/mkernel/EWProxyFramebuffer

https://code.google.com/archive/p/ioproxyvideofamily/source/default/source

Please note that these projects are not up to date in terms of supporting the latest macOS versions. Later versions of macOS have introduced things such as mandatory kernel extension signing that makes it harder for "hobby-developers" to produce something that can be shared for free on the internet in terms of kernel extensions. It also makes it harder for malware authors, which is the upside.

So take a look at these source repositories and you'll find your guidance - but don't expect them to be complete solutions.

Comment: Makes sense, same general idea I was considering. Thanks for the links, they helped understand the details.